# Dúvida na ordem dos campos da tabela em caso de chaves estrangeiras com menor importância hierarquicamente

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Olá amigos programadores! Sou apenas um iniciante no mundo da programação e no StackOverflow e preciso tirar uma dúvida!

Estou fazendo alguns ajustes em um banco de dados que estou trabalhando após encontrar ótimos guias de padronização dos campos e tabelas. Como tenho duas tabelas que possuem campos de contato (email, telefone, telefone_opcional) e endereço (logradouro, bairro, cep, etc...), decidi fazer uma tabela **contato** e uma tabela **endereco** que irão armazenar essas informações e terão uma relação com as outras duas tabelas mencionadas.

Como o meu objetivo é que esse banco fique "padronizado" para que outros programadores encontrem um banco normalizado e de fácil entendimento, o ideal é que as chaves estrangeiras fiquem sempre no início da tabela, após as chaves primárias, ou posso deixar os campos em ordem de importância, independente de serem chaves estrangeiras ou não?

Comment: Oi Hugo, essas questões de boas práticas são difíceis de responder, cada time possui suas práticas. Durante a etapa de design inicial do banco eu procuro ordenar campos por ordem de importância: IDs, chaves secundárias, campos importantes não nulos, demais campos não nulos, campos nulos e finalmente FKs.

Comment: Por outro lado, se o software já foi publicado eu evito reordenar campos. Sei que estamos no século 21 e ninguém deveria tepender de índices de coluna... mas... Enfim, em media durante a fase de design eu procuro deixar FKS que não são PKs no fim da tabela. Dito isso, isso é uma questão de opinião e você pode facilmente encontrar quem diga justamente o contrário.

Comment: Oi Anthony, agradeço pela resposta. Irei seguir sua metodologia!